# Creat a UIVIew with a dip

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Normally stuff like this I would prefer just using an image, but in my current situation i'm using lots of these shape views:

[image]

And i'm thinking what is the best way of making this dip on a UIView, Best if a cheaper way then DrawRect

Thanks